# Gluing buttons to the far left of the screen in a vertical BoxLayout in Swing

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, boxlayout

I've been having some trouble finding documentation for a specific trouble. You see, I wish to create a vertically aligned group of buttons that is glued to the far left of the screen, as shown in this edited photo.

Edited screen to show desired result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csvur.png]

However, I've no clue of how to achieve this. The documentation for BoxLayout makes mention of X-axis alignment, and having tested this, it seems focused on aligning components to one another, not components to relative portions of the screen.

My code is here:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TabbedPanes extends JFrame implements ActionListener  
{
    JTabbedPane tabs;
    JButton but1, but2, but3, but4, but5, but6, but7, but8, but9, but10, but11, but12;
    String string1, string2; 
    JPanel pan1, pan2, pan3, pan4, pan5, pan6, pan7, pan8;
    JFrame frame;
    JScrollPane scroll;

    public void Tabs()
    {
        Box theBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        but1 = new JButton("" + string1);
            but1.addActionListener(this);
        but3 = new JButton("" + string1);
        but4 = new JButton("" + string1);
        but5 = new JButton("" + string1);
        but6 = new JButton("" + string1);
        but7 = new JButton("" + string1);
        but8 = new JButton("" + string1);
        but9 = new JButton("" + string1);
        but10 = new JButton("" + string1);
        but11 = new JButton("" + string1);
        but12 = new JButton("" + string1);

        pan1 = new JPanel();                                                                   //instantiate the panel
        pan1.add(theBox);                                                                      //add the layout manager to the panel
            theBox.add(but1);                                                                  //add components to the layout manager 
                but1.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);      
            theBox.add(but3);
            theBox.add(but4);
            theBox.add(but5);
            theBox.add(but6);
            theBox.add(but7);
            theBox.add(but8);
            theBox.add(but9);
            theBox.add(but10);
            theBox.add(but11);
            theBox.add(but12);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(pan1);                                            //instantiate the JScrollPane with a parameter = the panel
            scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        pan2 = new JPanel();
        but2 = new JButton("" + string2);
        but2.addActionListener(this);
        pan2.add(but2);

        pan3 = new JPanel();

        pan4 = new JPanel();

        pan5 = new JPanel();

        pan6 = new JPanel();

        pan7 = new JPanel();

        pan8 = new JPanel();

        tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        pane.add(tabs);
        tabs.add("Mon", scroll);
        tabs.add("Tue", pan2);
        tabs.add("Wed", pan3);
        tabs.add("Thu", pan4);
        tabs.add("Fri", pan5);
        tabs.add("Sat", pan6);
        tabs.add("Sun", pan7);
        tabs.add("Notes", pan8);

        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == but1);
        {
            if(string1 == "Hello!")
            {
                string1 = "Goodbye.";
                but1.setText(string1);
            }

            else 
            {
                string1 = "Hello!";
                but1.setText(string1);
            }
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but2);
        {
            if(string2 == "Hello but in the other tab now!")
            {
                string2 = "I think you can see where this is going.";
                but2.setText(string2);
            }

            else 
            {
                string2 = "Hello but in the other tab now!";
                but2.setText(string2);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TabbedPanes TrueTabs = new TabbedPanes();
        TrueTabs.Tabs();    
    }   
}
```

And it produces this screen:

What the code currently produces:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZfki.png]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the future: 1) post a proper [mcve]. Your question is about button alignment. You don't need 7 tabs to demonstrate the problem. And you don't need 10 buttons. The less code we have to look at the easier it is to spot a problem. 2) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most variables are correct, but not all. Be consistent. 3) Don't use "==" for object comparison. Use the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: Aligning the buttons to the left can be achieved in several ways. It would be better to consider the entire layout. What do you want to do with the empty space on the right ?

Comment: My apologies, I've been a bit all over the place trying to test a whole bunch of things and forgot to clean up my code. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the Box to a panel which by default uses a FlowLayout with center alignment.

So you could do:

```
//pan1 = new JPanel();
pan1 = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT) );
```

Or you don't even need the additional panel.

Just add the Box to the scroll pane:

```
//JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(pan1);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(theBox);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you, and again, apologies for the terribly messy code.